# Create a dictonary from an Excel cell containing multiple questions and answers then a new dataframe with individual answers, questions are the column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got the wonderful task of compiling user responses to our ERP intake form. All of the responses are in one Excel cell as a string (see example below)

Good news: there are clear delimiters, "--" between each answer/question and each question has a ":" after it.

Bad news: It's a dynamic form, so the questions can be different based on the previous response, so a simple text to column on "-" wont work.

```
PO       Vendor    Form response in one cell
12345    asdf      "Question1: Answer -- Question2: Answer -- Question3: Answer -- ..."
56789    dgfdg     "Question1: different answer -- Different question2: Answer -- Question3: Answer -- ..."
```

I more or less figured out what to do, but I need to wrap this up CET EOD, or next morning at the latest. Excel mid(left right left righ) functions will not help me, as the "--" repeats. Maybe RegEx is the answer, but I never used it at looks complicated at glance.

What I thought of:

First, for the new dataframe I need the headers, so create a list, splitting the original string of all answers on "--". This will give a "dictionary" of answers/questions.

```
def dashbreak(mystr):
    newlst = mystr.split("--")
return newlst
```

Repeat this for all lines in the old dataframe, creating a monsterstring of all possible questions (column headers)

=> Need help

Create an actual dictionary by splitting the list on ":". The below function will give me nested lists, not a dictionary. Based on my limited knowledge the lookup later might be easier with a dict?

```
def colonbreak(lst):
    newlst = []
    counter = 0
for i in lst:
        newlst.append(lst[counter].split(":"))
        counter = counter+1
return newlst
```

Iterate over the list (?) to drop duplicate questions, index[x][0] is the question.

=> Need help on how to find the duplicates.

Create the "headers" list from the "clean" list (list comprehension?)

```
def create_headers(lst):
    header = []
    counter = 0
for i in lst:
        header.append(lst[counter][0])
        counter = counter+1
return header
```

Create a new pandas dataframe, copy over the PO and vendor fields, assign the headers list to column names, (append header list with PO and vendor). This will give me a spreadsheet with a lot of columns, each column is the actual form question. => check

Create a function that grabs the raw answer string based on PO number from the original df (iterating over rows), calls the two break functions, then iterates over the columns in the current row.

Vague, incomplete idea:

```
def plshelp():

    for column in rawDataframe:
        for cell in column:
            dashbroken = dashbreak(cell)
            colonbroken = colonbreak(dashbroken)
            counter = 0
            for i in colonbroken:
                if colonbroken[counter][0] == newdfColumnHeader:
                    newdfCell.value = colonbroken[counter][1] #the answer part of the sublists
                    counter = counter+1
                else:
                    counter = counter+1    
    return
```

Save the dataframe to excel => check

Apart from the actual solution I'd be glad for tips on how to clean up the code I've written and make it more pythonic.

Example result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [12345, "asdf", "answer", "answer", None, None, "answer"],
        [56789, "dgfdg", None, None, "answer", "answer", "answer"],
    ],
    columns=[
        "PO",
        "Vendor",
        "Question1",
        "Question2",
        "DifferentQuestion1",
        "DifferentQuestion2",
        "Question3",
    ],
)
df.head()
```

Thanks to Tõnis Piip there's a partial solution, however the columns are added sequentially, and only if such a column does not exist already.

This messes up answer orders, as for example the first question is "Which Market is this related to?" and the second is "Please select the Country for {selected market}". When there's a new response to the "Region" question the next question/column is added to end, but the following question (what are you purchasing) already exists as it is always the third question. There are a few questions that are the same.

Is it possible to add counter that checks the index of the current question, and if it's a new one, then injecting the new column at the appropriate index instead of at the end? So the first question is always "Which region", the next x columns "Which country in {region}", etc.

Comment: Just so it's clear, the new dataframe has columns [PO, Vendor, Question1, Question2, ..., QuestionN]? And you want to add the respective PO, Vendor and each answer to the rows of this new dataframe?

Comment: Yes, the new dataframe would have the two original columns, PO, Vendor and all of the answer strings as new columns. Will edit the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution to this problem and also made some adjustments for cleaner code.
You probably have to change the column names to the appropriate ones used in your data.

```
new_columns = ["PO", "Vendor"]

for row in rawDataframe["Answers"]:
    dash_separated = row.split("--")
    questions = [answer.split(":")[0].strip() for answer in dash_separated]
    for q in questions:
        if q not in new_columns:
            new_columns.append(q)
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)

for index, row in rawDataframe.iterrows():
    dash_separated = row["Answers"].split("--")

    questions = [answer.split(":")[0].strip() for answer in dash_separated]
    questions.insert(0, "Vendor")
    questions.insert(0, "PO")

    answers = [answer.split(":")[1].strip() for answer in dash_separated]
    answers.insert(0, row["Vendor"])
    answers.insert(0, row["PO"])

    data_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        data_dict[questions[i]] = answers[i]
    newDataFrame = newDataFrame.append(data_dict, ignore_index=True)

newDataFrame.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Input test data (from csv in lieu of excel table):

```
PO,Vendor,Answers
12345,asdfg,"Question1: Answer1 -- Question2: Answer2"
54321,qwerty,"Question3: Answer3 -- Question4: Answer4"
```

Output (newDataFrame .head()):

```
    PO      Vendor  Question1   Question2   Question3   Question4
0   12345   asdfg   Answer1     Answer2     
1   54321   qwerty                          Answer3     Answer4
```

Comment: Will have to test this, one of the biggest issues with the dataset that even the questions can be different, for example the first question is "which region?" - the second question could be "which country in LATAM" or "which country in EMEA". The forms themselves are not static, so 100 POs could have 90 different questions, I need to capture this.

Comment: @Asrakh I believe I figured out the dynamic dataframe issue as well now.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working, one issue I have realized (I would have done the same mistake) is that the columns are add sequentially, and only if such a column does not exist already. This messes up answer orders, as for example the first question is "Which Market is this related to?" and the second is "Please select the Country for {selected market}". There are a few questions down the line where one of the questions/columns already exist, however the followup question get's added to the end. I'll amend the original question as I'm out of characters.